# Spring JPA Projection - Queried Data from jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I don't know if this is possible but I am trying to project data queried from JPA repository into a DTO

I have the following query:

```
@Query(value =
        "SELECT crop.id, count(*) as total " +
        "FROM xxx.crop_sub_plot " +
        "join crop on crop.id = crop_sub_plot.crop_id " +
        "join sub_plot on sub_plot.id = crop_sub_plot.sub_plot_id " +
        "where sub_plot.enabled = true " +
        "group by crop_id " +
        "order by total DESC;", nativeQuery = true)
List<CropUsedView> findCropsInUseOrderByDesc();
```

and the DTO:

```
public class CropUsedView implements Serializable{

private BigInteger id;
private BigInteger total;

public CropUsedView() {
}

public CropUsedView(BigInteger id, BigInteger total) {
    this.id = id;
    this.total = total;
}

//getters && setters
```

I'm getting the error:

> No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigInteger] to type [net.xxx.crop.CropUsedView]

I don't really know if this is possible, any suggestion?

**EDIT:** this is how the data is returning when I run the query on MySql and is how I want to be converted to a DTO:

[image]

Comment: Try to use `Long` instead of `BigInteger`

Comment: You're returning two values, `crop.id` and a `count`, and telling Spring that's a list of `CropUsedView`. Perhaps you meant to only return a single object?

Comment: @Cepr0 I have tried that but dont work

Comment: @BrunoM24 what is the error?

Comment: @chrylis I want a List of DTO, the DTO have the two values, like when I do List<Crop> findAll(); this works

Comment: @Cepr0 is the same error

Comment: didi you try to write `SELECT crop.id as id ...... `?

Comment: @BrunoM24 try [interface base projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) instead of class-base one. And also add the alias to `corp.id` (`crop.id as id`)...

Comment: Just stop for a moment and think about exactly how the mapping is supposed to work. Literally draw the SELECT return values and the DTOs on paper.

Comment: @chrylis I have edit the post with a image how data is being returned whe I run on mysql and is how I want to be mapped to the dto, I have the DTO with the same props

Comment: do you need a native query? Can that be an jpql? then you could write something like `@Query(select new com.example.CropUsedView(c.id, total) from Crop c, count(c.id) total inner join c.subplot s where s.enabled = true group by c)`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning two values: the id and a count (both can be mapped in a `long` or `BigDecimal`). But Hibernate, as it's not mapped directly into an object, is just returning `BigDecimal[]`.

To solve this, you should use a custom mapper: `UserType` (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html). This allows you to map whatever response into an object with a manual parsing.